# ACCESO A SISTEMA EN JAVA WEB JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema web que tiene el login para acceder, pero también se puede acceder al sistema saltándose el login solo colocando el url. Ejemplo: La pagina que sigue al loguearse es el inicio del usuario(`InicioUsuario.jsp`) y puedo acceder si me redirecciono a  **localhost:8084/servF/InicioUsuario.jsp** Quisiera saber como evito eso por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde tiempos inmemoriales, se inventó lo que se conoce como *sesión HTTP* del lado del servidor, de la que puedes tirar en estos casos. Esta sesión:

- Permite reconocer diferentes acciones, realizadas generalmente desde un navegador, como una secuencia de acciones (de allí el nombre de sesión). Para este efecto, se utiliza generalmente una *cookie*, aunque hay otras formas (por ejemplo, un parámetro que se añade a cada petición `GET`/`POST`, etc.).
- Se puede almacenar valores en la sesión, que existen más allá de la petición que estamos atendiendo, por la duración de la sesión. Almacenamos valores en la sesión cuándo ocurren acciones, como un *request* que da como resultado un inicio de sesión satisfactorio, y recuperamos estos valores posteriormente, por ejemplo cuándo intenta accederese a una parte privada del sitio, para validar si realmente se ha cumplido con el inicio de sesión.

En resumen, cuando un usuario ha iniciado sesión correctamente en tu sitio, puedes almacenar un valor en la sesión y luego, en cada página *privada*, lo primero que haces es consultar si el inicio de sesión exitoso ha ocurrido, y si no, redirigir al usuario a la página de inicio de sesión:

Digamos que al ocurrir un inicio de sesión exitoso, guardamos el atributo `User_ID` en la sesión (entre otros).

Usando una sesión implícita:

```
<%
    session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session.getAttribute("User_ID") == null)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
%> 
<body>
   etc...
```

Cuándo hay un inicio de sesión exitoso, almacenas este valor, y probablemente otros, por ejemplo:

```
String result=LoginDAO.loginCheck(loginBean);
 
if (result.equals("true")) {
    session.setAttribute("User_ID", loginBean.getUser_ID());
    session.setAttribute("UserName", loginBean.getUserName());
    response.sendRedirect("menu.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?status=error");
}
```

Y cuándo el usuario hace logout invocamos al método `invalidate()` de la sesión para borrar todo su contenido:

```
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo completo [aquí](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example) (en inglés).

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta rápida es usando la sesión. En la sesión puedes guardar información de tal forma que al revisarla puedes saber si la persona ya hizo login.... si no lo ha hecho, pues la devuelves al login.... y esa verificación la haces en cada una de las páginas accesibles.

Comment: Por favor trata de no responder preguntas mal planteadas.